# ip netns returns "Operation not supported" in docker container on m1 mac

Tags: docker, ip, apple-m1

I have a docker image in amd64 that is used for development. Previously we used intel macs and we are trying to run this container on arm64 (m1). If I try to run any `ip netns` command in this container I get `request send failed: Operation not supported`. The issue is only present in m1 macs and not in intel macs. I tried adding `--privileged --cap-add=all` to the docker run command but that had no effect. I'm not sure what to do to troubleshoot & fix the issue.